# Leaflet : Handling a GeoJSON composed of multiple GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I built a map using leaflet, with big GeoJSON regions, which are composed of multiple 'smaller' GeoJSON regions.

I'm using Leaftet-Ajax to call them like that :

```
var Rennes = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Rennes.geojson", {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

Here, Rennes.geojson is composed of 3 smaller geojson. I use geojson-merge to merge them all together in one geojson file. 
I also tried the method with L.layergroup to regroup the smaller regions :

```
var Bordeaux1 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Bordeaux_1.json");
var Bordeaux2 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Bordeaux_2.json");
var Bordeaux3 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Bordeaux_3.json");
var Bordeaux = L.layerGroup([Bordeaux1, Bordeaux2, Bordeaux3], {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

( I don't know which is the best way )

So next, when the user click, I need to zoom in on the BIG region he chose. 
I use this great tutorial to do it : http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html.

Everything is working fine except that with the e.target method, the changes only affect the small regions.

I'm lost and I don't know how to target only the big geojson or all the smaller ones a the same time...

Answer (score 1):

The `onEachFeature` and `style` options are available in the `L.GeoJSON` constructor, **not** on the `L.LayerGroup` constructor, and they must be specified in the same options hashmap. In other words:

```
var Bordeaux1 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Bordeaux_1.json", {onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: style});
var Bordeaux2 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Bordeaux_2.json", {onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: style});
var Bordeaux3 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("src/js/DI_Bordeaux_3.json", {onEachFeature: onEachFeature, style: style});
var Bordeaux = L.layerGroup([Bordeaux1, Bordeaux2, Bordeaux3]).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to fit the bounds of a group of layers, do not use an `L.LayerGroup`, but instead an [`L.FeatureGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup): it has a [`.getBounds()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds) that computes the extent of all the layers inside.

Then you probably need to be cautious about to which objects you attach your listener (the one that implements the zoom to bounds on click). By using `onEachFeature` on a GeoJSON group, you attach one listener per child layer, hence `event.target` is the individual clicked feature.

If you attach your listener to the GeoJSON group itself, or to a Feature Group, `event.target` would then be the group (hence `event.target.getBounds()` would give the extent of all the children, not of the individual clicked one).

And `event.layer` would give the individual clicked layer, in case you want to know which one was originally clicked.